# uitableview cell does't update cell height after I change a subview's height constraint

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have a custom cell with a button and a blue blank view in it, when the button is tapped, the cell should change the blue view's cell height constraint. But now when the blue view's height is changed, the cell height doesn't change, i want the cell height to change the same amount as the blue view, but now it doesn't. 
Here is the constraint.

[image]

the result is

[image]

what is want is update the cell height to accommodate the blue view.
here is the code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TestZanTableViewCell";
    TestZanTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static TestZanTableViewCell *cell;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TestZanTableViewCell"];
    }

   [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

   NSLog(@"%f",  [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + 1.0f);
   return [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + 1.0f;
```

}

```
- (void)configureCell:(TestZanTableViewCell *)cell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (cell.tapped) {
        cell.heightOfLikeView.constant = 50;

    }
    cell.testLabel.text = @"Helloworld";
    [cell.zanButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

 - (void)didTapButton:(id)sender {
// Cast Sender to UIButton
     UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    // Find Point in Superview
    CGPoint pointInSuperview = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:self.tableView];

 // Infer Index Path
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInSuperview];

    TestZanTableViewCell *cell = (TestZanTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.tapped = YES;
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [cell.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the table view and explicitly tell the tableview that, that particular cell has a different height.

You can refresh the table view as follows:

```
[tableview reloadData]
```

Or if you want to only refresh the one cell/ specific cells

```
[tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathOfYourCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

You will also need to add the height function to your TableView's delegate so that the table view can load with custom heights for each cell.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (hasTheTallBlueView) {
        return largerValue;
    }
    return regularHeight;
}
```

Comment: I did that, it didn't work, that's why i ask here, thanks for you reply, btw, i use autolayout, i implemented the method using cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + 1.0f for the heightforrowatindexpath method

Comment: Could you post your code please? It's hard to tell what might be happening if we can't see what you've done.